# How do I trigger fitVids for multiple, dynamically generated ids on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm working on a responsive tumblr-theme based on the 1140GRID. To make the static videos fit the column, I used the jquery fitvids plugin. 
My setup code looks like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#post_{PostID}").fitVids();
  });
```

and the accompanying html like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="ninecol"> //grid I want it to fit into
      {Block:Video}     
        <div id="post_{PostID}">
          {Video-500}
        </div>
      {/Block:Video}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I trigger fitVids for multiple, dynamically generated ids on a page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to put that closing DIV inside the video block.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="ninecol"> //grid I want it to fit into
      {Block:Video}     
      <div id="post_{PostID}">
        {Video-500}
      </div>
      {/Block:Video}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, you could target all the subdivs of ninecol.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ninecol > div').fitVids();
});
</script>
```